# How did you sleep today? - meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

Usually the question "**How did you sleep today**?" is about the **quality** of the sleeping or about the **position** of the sleeping?

In other words, if I read or hear “how did you sleep last night”, what should I understand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you're a vampire, normally you'd be asked

> How did you sleep *last night*?

The questioner is wanting to know if your sleep was restful or if it was disturbed in any way.

Comment: and if he didn't sleep at night but in the day time? By the way, I really didn't understand what you said about the vampire, I'd like to get explain and learn something new:)

Comment: Vampires sleep during the day and are awake at night.

Comment: If he *regularly* sleeps during the day and is awake at night (e.g. he works the night shift) then one might ask "How did you sleep *today*?"  But we can't really use *today* in this context without *some* kind of special justification for it. A typical question might be *How was your nap?*

Comment: many workers sleep at the day because they work at nights. I'd not call them vampires:)  Anyway, it means it's correct to say "How did you sleep last night?" meaning about the quality rather than the position. Right?

Comment: Absent a context where the discussion centers on sleep position (fetal position, on stomach, on the back) the question *How did you sleep?* normally is asking whether you slept well.

Comment: @Wittyloquacity In what context does asking "in what position did you sleep last night" make any sense? Do people in your culture ask each other about their sleeping positions as small talk?

Comment: A medical question for example. Anyway, my question was to know what this question means. It could be a medical question for example and people rarely use it (and the way to ask about quality was different. for example: "How well did you sleep last night?" but I took into consideration that this is the one that common among people. I just wasn't sure about that:)

Comment: @Wittyloquacity This sort of misunderstanding can be a source of humour: Q:"How did you sleep last night?" A: "I closed my eyes." or Q: "Did you make your bed?" A: "No, I bought it."

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong in what I say, which is based only on my experience of other people’s speech and writing.

First, your question is not fully clear.  It might be:-

> 1. If I read or hear “how did you sleep last night”, what should I understand?

Or it might be:-

> What is the right (or best) way to ask about the quality (or position) of somebody’s sleep.

If we take 1., I would say that under almost all circumstances we should understand the question as one about the quality of sleep.  Why?  Because in almost all circumstances it is an odd and intrusive question, unless you were a mountaineer halfway up a rock face, or Batman/girl.  Also such a silly question might tempt a frivolous answer, such as:  “On my back, with my bottom against the headboard and my legs up the wall.”

A more reasonable context might be after a night when neighbours were playing rock all night long at full blast.  Then you might wonder

> How did you  sleep  last night?

But if question 1.  is the issue, I should say that the most common (and least ambiguous) way of asking it is to say:

> Did you sleep well last night?

And if you spent the night under the same roof, and meet up over breakfast,

> Did you sleep well? is enough